# How do I use a forward slash in my api call?

Tags: jquery, json

Hello all Im starting to use APIs for development purposes and ive come accross and api call that uses / as a means of separating values I've been putting ?

```
var requestURL = 'https://alpha.openaddressesuk.org/addresses.json?';

    $.getJSON(requestURL, {
        'street' : street,
        'town'  : town,
        'postcode' : postcode,
    }, function(data) {
```

the result of the requesturl would be https://alpha.openaddressesuk.org/addresses.json?street=STREET?town=TOWN?postcode=POSTCODE

but I've noticed that some apis have / instead of ? in the request URL

So how would I do this

```
 var requestURL = 'http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/station/{{STATIONNAME}}/{{STATION DATE}}/{{STATION TIME}}/timetable.json?app_id=APPID&app_key=APIKEY&train_status=passenger';

    $.getJSON(requestURL, {
        'stationname' : stationname,
        'date'  : date,
        'time' : time,
    }, function(data) {
            console.log(data)
    }
```

but wouldn't that put ? in-between each parameter?

Comment: No, `?` marks start of parameters while `/` marks sub-directories of domain. `www.example.com/v3/uk/timetable.json?app_id=APPID` is valid URL

Comment: Why don't you create the right request URL before you even call the  `getJSON` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Percent encoding on the station name to change the / into `%2F`. Full details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

In javascript this can be achieved using `encodeURIComponent(str);` eg

```
// Build request URL (assumes date and time are strings in the
// correct format)
var requestURL = 
    'http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/train/station/' + 
    encodeURIComponent(stationname) + '/' + date + '/' + 
    time + '/timetable.json';

$.getJSON(requestURL, {
    'app_id': app_id,
    'app_key': app_key,
    'train_status': 'passenger',
}, function(data) {
        console.log(data)
}
```